# How to handle "null primary key encountered" exception in eclipselink?

Tags: java, exception, jpa, eclipselink, java-ee-6

... Null primary key encountered in unit of work clone ...

exception in eclipselink(2.0.2 with 2.0 jpa) literally meaning that id in my entity is <=0 (for primitive types). Though debug here states that everything's fine and I have nothing to worry about. My AS is glassfish v3. Can any one point out what may cause such behavior?

Comment: have you checked all the entities that relate to the current one and are cascaded through it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After minor investigation on smaller scale app this error was not reproduced. Consequently there's something going on inside an app somewhere which in most part is not related to eclipselink.

Comment: So what was it? I run into the same problem when loading entity and adding new entity as a child collection item

Comment: Well... I can say that it was 2y ago and I'm glad it never showed up again. :)